# where is the PATH for users set in linux, before any shell, or sudo, pam.d changes it?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I noticed that in Raspbian that if I run a command via ssh without using a shell, I get the following `$PATH`;

```
$ ssh pi@raspberrypi env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

I can't find where this path is actually set.

I am assuming that neither `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc` are sourced, because its not a login and its not an interactive shell. It looks like it would probably visit `bashrc`, but that it wouldn't get very far;

```
# cat /etc/bash.bashrc 
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

**pam**
However it looks like the session would be processed through pam, and the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` suggests that `/etc/environment`, `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` and `/etc/default/locale` are used to set environment variables;

```
# Read environment variables from /etc/environment and
# /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
# In Debian 4.0 (etch), locale-related environment variables were moved to
# /etc/default/locale, so read that as well.
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

However on this machine, none of those files contain any references to setting the path. e.g.

```
# cat /etc/default/locale
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8

# cat /etc/environment
root@raspberrypi:~# 

# cat /etc/security/pam_env.conf | grep "^[^#;]"
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

**login.defs**
The only place I could find a path set similar to

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

was in the /etc/login.defs file;

```
login.defs:ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin: \
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

It looks like that latter path has the elements in the right order, but with the `sbin` components stripped out. However the docs for `login.defs` suggest this file is [mostly deprecated](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/login.defs.5.html);

> Much of the functionality that used to be provided by the shadow
>          password suite is now handled by PAM. Thus, /etc/login.defs is no
>          longer used by passwd(1), or less used by login(1), and su(1). Please
>          refer to the corresponding PAM configuration files instead.

**/home/pi/.bashrc**
The pi users was created with some skeleton files, but none of them would appear to be read for a non-interactive, non-login shell;

```
# cat /home/pi/.bashrc 
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

**/home/pi/.profile**

```
# cat /home/pi/.profile 
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
```

Is that original $PATH hard coded into a binary somewhere, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard-coded in the `sshd` binary.

```
$ strings /usr/sbin/sshd |grep /usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games
```

In the OpenSSH portable code, that's [`_PATH_STDPATH`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/defines.h) which defaults to `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` for both root and non-root. The [Debian build rules](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-ssh/openssh.git/tree/debian/rules) set this to `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` for root, `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games` for non-root on Ubuntu, `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` on installation live media  (udeb), and `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games` for non-root otherwise.